# CSS Animations: How do I apply transform after every iteration?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate a list of 4 divs within a container div.

I wish to move them up after each second.

I have defined 2 animations: scaleUp and slideUp.

```
@keyframes scaleUp {
 0%{
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
   }
100%{
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-90px);
   }
 }
```

and

```
@keyframes slideUp {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-90px);
  }
}
```

I then applied the animations to the divs in the following way:

```
.animated:nth-child(1){
  animation: slideUp 1s 4, scaleUp 1s ease;
}

.animated:nth-child(2){
  animation: slideUp 1s 4, scaleUp 1s ease 1s;
}

.animated:nth-child(3){
  animation: slideUp 1s 4, scaleUp 1s ease 2s;
}

.animated:nth-child(4){
  animation: slideUp 1s 4, scaleUp 1s ease 3s;
}
```

where animated is the class I gave to the divs.

The problem is, that the animation resets after every iteration and the divs start from their initial position after every iteration.

I tried `animation-fill-mode: forwards` on slideUp, but the transformations get applied only after all the 4 iterations are complete. How do I apply the transformation after every iteration?

P.S. [You can view the code here](https://codepen.io/priyank1205/pen/pwzJjQ)

Comment: Can you use JavaScript on this project or are you limited to CSS?

Comment: @ArnauFernández I am limited to only CSS for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make your animation for slideup go over 4 keyframes -90px each frame and then have a separate scaleup animation for each box based on their position at the time of the animation:

```css
/*.center{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}*/

.container{
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px 1px rgba(5,5,5,0.14);
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*.active{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}*/

@keyframes scaleUp {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-90px);
  }
}

@keyframes scaleUp1 {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-180px);
  }
}

@keyframes scaleUp2 {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-180px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-270px);
  }
}

@keyframes scaleUp3 {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-270px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-360px);
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  25%{
    transform: translateY(-90px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateY(-180px);
  }
  75%{
    transform: translateY(-270px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-360px);
  }
}

.animated:nth-child(1){
  animation: slideUp 4s, scaleUp 1s ease;
  animation-play-state: running;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
.animated:nth-child(2){
  animation: slideUp 4s, scaleUp1 1s ease 1s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
.animated:nth-child(3){
  animation: slideUp 4s, scaleUp2 1s ease 2s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
.animated:nth-child(4){
  animation: slideUp 4s, scaleUp3 1s ease 3s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card animated">
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      </div>
      <div class="card animated">
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      </div>
      <div class="card animated">
        3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      </div>
      <div class="card animated">
        4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!
Is there an alternative to defining the four animations(scaleUp 1,2,3,4), that would make sure that the css file is of as less size as possible?

Comment: Hmmm, don't think you can - you would need some sort of preprocessor like sass or less (but then  I think it just generates a css file which will still be the same size)